# overwrite xor in groovy

Tags: methods, groovy, overwrite

I am looking for an way to overwrite xor on an groovy script.

I've created a base class for my script where a Object is defined. This object already has a method `public Object xor(String var)` which works like `myobject^"foo"`. What I want is way to access this method like `myobject^foo` where foo handled like a normal String.

Comment: Can you provide some more info? I'm not sure what you mean by `What I want is way to access this method like myobject^foo where foo handled like a normal String.`?

Comment: I've written a baseclass in java for my groovy scripts. There I defined a object which provides access to a graph database. I want to access these nodes by name for example `db^nodename` or `db^nodename^nodename2...`. The Method I already have is `public Object xor(String var)` which works but unfortunately I have to write `db^"nodename"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your answer @daggett I found a method which handles missing properties:

```
public abstract class MyBaseScript extends Script implements GroovyObject {
    protected class A {
       public Object xor(String var) {
          //do fancy stuff
          return var;
       }
    }

    protected A foo = new A();        

    //method which handles missing properties
    public Object propertyMissing(String name) {
       return name;
    }
}
```

How do I start my scripts:

```
Binding binding = new Binding();
// passing parameters
binding.setVariable("arg0", arg0);
binding.setVariable("args", arg1);

// Compiler Config
CompilerConfiguration cc = new CompilerConfiguration();
ImportCustomizer ic = new ImportCustomizer();
// add some imports for e.g.
ic.addImports("java.awt.Color", "java.util.Calendar",...);
cc.addCompilationCustomizers(ic);
// set BaseClass
cc.setScriptBaseClass("de.MyBaseScript");
// execute script
GroovyClassLoader loader = new GroovyClassLoader();
shell = new GroovyShell(loader, binding, cc);
Script gscript = shell.parse(groovyScriptAsAFile);
Object o = gscript.run();
```

Answer (score 0):

as i understand you want to do somehow that

```
(myobject^"foo") == (myobject^foo)
```

so, in your script you can redefine method getProperty() so in your script access to foo property will return "foo" string..

```
class A{
    public Object xor(Object o){
        println "xor $o"
        return o
    }
}

public getProperty(String key){
    if(key in ['out'])return super.getProperty(key) //skip standard properties
    return key
}

def myobject=new A()
assert (myobject^foo) == (myobject^"foo")
```

**but i don't see any benefits :)**

Comment: in this case -  no way. you can only do it only for property. in groovy `myobject.getProperty('foo') == myobject.'foo' == myobject.foo`

Comment: This seems to help :). But I 'am writting my Object ( for your example A) in java. So ['out'] is the list of properties (in the metaclass) which my Object has?

`public class A extends GroovyObjectSupport {

public Object xor(String var) {
  Object o = 
  return o;
 }
 
 @Override
 public Object getProperty(String property){
  Object o = null;
  if((o = super.getProperty(property) ) == null)
   return property;
  return o;
 }

}`

But I get a MissingPropertyException. What is ['out']? How can I call it in java?

Comment: where from you going to call your object? from groovy script? if yes `out` s a standard `groovy.lang.Script` property that is used for `println` function. and in my case i'm redefining `getProperty` for the script and not for the object. just check who is throwing MissingPropertyException and you'll understand.